# C# Displaying data in a winform applications similarly to a web application

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to present information from my database,but not in a table ( the reason why I am not going for datagridview). My question is, is it possible to display contents styled the way you would see them on a web page, for example the way you see them in an online shop( each in its own container, displaying main characteristics), instead of a table ? In an ASP.NET app I could usually achieve this functionality with following code on my index page:

```
@foreach (var item in @Model.Items){
<div id="objectDiv" class="border-1 d-inline-flex">
    <div class="container">
        <label asp-for="@item.Address">Address: @item.Address</label> <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may consider using a WebView2 control: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Answer (score 0):

Winforms works different than html+css but you can achieve some nice, dynamic layouts using 3rd party libraries such as [Telerik](https://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx) or [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/) (my preference). To do what you described with the generic controls, do the following:

1. Add a panel to the form. Name: panel1.
2. The following will populate the panel with label controls.

   ```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var items = new List<Item> { new Item { Address = "123 Main Street" }, new Item { Address = "234 Maple Street" } }; 
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            var lbl = new Label { Text = item.Address };
            panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            lbl.Top = (panel1.Controls.Count * 30) + 15;
        }
      }
    }

    public class Item
    {
            public string Address { get; set; }
    }
   ```

Comment: You could suggest to build a UserControl instead of *sparse* Controls, so you could also design a nice *DIV-like container*. A FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel could help to automate the layout.

Comment: @jjthebig1 are there any free libraries that support this functionality, since this is not a serious project ( a challenge I set for myself ), or is using an alternate paid framework for winforms the only other way this functionality could be achieved?

Comment: @Tuna239, Syncfunction is another vendor of controls for winforms and they have a free "Community" license. I haven't used them extensively but they seemed to be pretty good.

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Click the Claim Free License button, not the Free Trial.